# Using seekbars to change RGB values android studio

Tags: android, rgb, android-seekbar

I was wondering how to change my code to make it work properly:

```
Red.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            seekr = Red.getProgress();
            seekg = Green.getProgress();
            seekb = Blue.getProgress();
            button1.setBackgroundColor(
                    0xff000000
                            +seekr*0x10000
                            +seekg*0x100
                            +seekb
            );
            button2.setBackgroundColor(
                    0xff000000
                            +seekr*0x10000
                            +seekg*0x100
                            +seekb
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

this is the method that i'm using to change the value of the Red parameter, and i'm controlling also the other 2 colors in the same way.
The problem is that when all the seekbars are set on 0 the background color of the buttons is black, and if they are all set at the maximum value the background color is grey; so i can't have  the white color.
Why is this code not working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are wanting white or not but could try using:

```
button1.SetBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, seekr, seekg, seekb));
button2.SetBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, seekr, seekg, seekb));
```

Comment: Yes, and seekr/seekg/seekb values should be in the [0, 255] range